Unable to Access Node.js Proxy URL from Browser on DigitalOcean Server
I'm currently setting up a Node.js proxy server on a DigitalOcean droplet to bypass CORS restrictions. While the proxy server seems to be running fine, I'm unable to access the proxy URL from the browser. Here are the details of my setup:
Server Environment:

DigitalOcean Droplet
Cyberpanel
Node.js v12.22.9
PM2 for process management

Proxy Server Code (app.js):
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;

app.use(cors());

app.get('/proxy', (req, res) => {
  const targetUrl = req.query.target;
  if (!targetUrl) {
    return res.status(400).send('Missing target URL');
  }

  request(targetUrl, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
    res.send(body);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


PM2 Management:

Started the proxy server using PM2
Verified that the server is running and listening on port 5000

When I run the following curl command on the server, I get the expected response:
curl "http://myip:5000/proxy?target=http://example.com"

What is the response you're getting in the browser? Which browser are you using?

"Bypass CORS restrictions". You've got it backwards. CORS is not something you bypass. CORS is what allows you to relax restrictions.

This site can’t be reached  took too long to respond. Its fine when i am sending a curl request from the same server but not working from the browser.

@jub0bs I understand, Thanks for correcting me, I am looking to bypass the cors restriction to be able to access the contents within an iframe.

FIXED:
It was cyberpanel firewall blocking the server.
Also had to update nodejs to latest version.
